# Order by "position", but place 0 last

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, sorting, activerecord

I have a table with Sliders:

```
 | id | position | 
 | 1  | 2        | 
 | 2  | 0        | 
 | 3  | 0        | 
 | 4  | 1        |
```

And I want to order them by `position`, where a position of 0 is treated as if *unsorted*.
Unsorted records should then be sorted on some other column (`created_at`). For the sake of the example, ordering by ID as secondary sort is fine.

A simple

```
SELECT "sliders".* FROM "sliders" ORDER BY position ASC, id ASC
```

selects them, but, obviously, sorts the 0 above the 1, giving me:

```
 | id | position | 
 | 2  | 0        | 
 | 3  | 0        | 
 | 4  | 1        | 
 | 1  | 2        |
```

But, I want a query that returns:

```
 | id | position | 
 | 4  | 1        | 
 | 1  | 2        | 
 | 2  | 0        | 
 | 3  | 0        |
```

Sorting the "unsorted" items under the sorted ones.

Is this possible with SQL, and if so, how? Is this a good approach at all, or would I be better off with some e.g. another column containing a "is_sorted" flag?

I am using ActiveRecord (Ruby on Rails) as ORM, so maybe that offers a helper that makes this easier?

Edit: the SQL is for sqlite now, but should be portable to MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
order by
   case when position = 0 then 2 else 1 end,
   position
```

First forces all zeros to come last,
THEN, order by position

Comment: To make this a little more portable, should it not be `then max(position)` instead? *edit:* never mind, I see how it works, it introduces a new "column" that is 0 or 1, and uses position as secondary sort option.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT "sliders".* 
FROM   "sliders" 
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN position = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, 
          position ASC, 
          id ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you do something like this? I am sure it would work.

```
SELECT "sliders".* FROM "sliders" where position != 0 ORDER BY position ASC, id ASC
UNION
SELECT "sliders".* FROM "sliders" where position = 0 ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Personally i would prefer the union solution than the ORDER BY CASE.

Comment: Why is that preferred, @Cid54?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [TSQL CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT "sliders".* FROM "sliders" 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN position = 0 THEN 999 ELSE position END, id ASC
```

Comment: From my limited SQL-knowledge, your solution would break when I havea column with a `position` above 999. Seems it should either use a `max(position)` in place of `999` or use the `ORDER B case...end DESC, position ASC` as provided by other answers.